# parsec: string choice parser with useful error messages

Tags: haskell, parsec, parser-combinators

Let's have following parser:

```
parser :: GenParser Char st String
parser = choice (fmap (try . string) ["head", "tail", "tales"]
                    <?> "expected one of ['head', 'tail', 'tales']")
```

When we parse the malformed input "ta" it will return the defined error but because of backtracking it will also talk about `unexpected "t"` at first position instead of `unexpected " "` at position 3.

Is there an easy (or built-in) way of matching one of multiple expected strings that produces good error messages? I am talking about showing the correct position and in this case something like `expected "tail" or "tales"` instead of our hard-coded error message.

Comment: You could write [your own choice operator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12169088/235908).

Comment: I don't think it is that easy. Just using `<|>` doesn't work as this is exactly what `choice` is doing. I would need to inspect Char by Char and eliminate impossible choices on each step. I asked because it seems to be a common problem. Strange if there weren't a standard solution.

Comment: Ah, it seems the difference and the cause of your problem is `try`.

Comment: Yes, it's doing the backtracking I mentioned in the initial post. It's needed for `choice` and also when going through the individual parsers with `<|>`. Without it the failed parsers will consume input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not hard to cook up a function which does this correctly. We'll just rip one character off at a time, using `Data.Map` to find the shared suffixes:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Map hiding (empty)
import Text.Parsec hiding ((<|>))
import Text.Parsec.Char

-- accept the empty string if that's a choice
possiblyEmpty :: Stream s m Char => [String] -> ParsecT s u m String
possiblyEmpty ss | "" `elem` ss = pure ""
                 | otherwise    = empty

chooseFrom :: Stream s m Char => [String] -> ParsecT s u m String
chooseFrom ss
     =  foldWithKey (\h ts parser -> liftA2 (:) (char h) (chooseFrom ts) <|> parser)
                    empty
                    (fromListWith (++) [(h, [t]) | h:t <- ss])
    <|> possiblyEmpty ss
```

We can verify in ghci that it succesfully matches `"tail"` and `"tales"`, and that it asks for `i` or `l` after a failed parse starting with `ta`:

```
*Main> parse (chooseFrom ["head", "tail", "tales"]) "" "tail"
Right "tail"
*Main> parse (chooseFrom ["head", "tail", "tales"]) "" "tales"
Right "tales"
*Main> parse (chooseFrom ["head", "tail", "tales"]) "" "tafoo"
Left (line 1, column 3):
unexpected "f"
expecting "i" or "l"
```

Answer (score 2):

## Old answer for old nonworking example

Which version of `parsec` do you have installed? 3.1.9 does this for me:

```hs
Prelude> :m + Text.Parsec Text.Parsec.String
Prelude Text.Parsec Text.Parsec.String> :set prompt Main>
Main> let parser = choice (map (try . string) ["foo", "fob", "bar"]) :: GenParser Char st String
Main> runParser parser () "Hey" "fo "
Left "Hey" (line 1, column 1):
unexpected " "
expecting "foo", "fob" or "bar"
Main> runParser parser () "Hey" "fo"
Left "Hey" (line 1, column 1):
unexpected end of input
expecting "foo", "fob" or "bar"
```

The added `<?> error_message` doesn't change anything except that it changes that last line to `expecting expected one of ['foo', 'fob', 'bar']`.

## How to extract more errors out of Parsec

So this is one of those cases where you shouldn't trust the error message to be exhaustive about the information that is available in the system. Let me give a funky `Show` instance for `Text.Parsec.Error:Message` (which is basically what it would be if it were `deriving (Show)`) so that you can see what's coming out of Parsec:

```
Main> :m + Text.Parsec.Error
Main> instance Show Message where show m = (["SysUnExpect", "UnExpect", "Expect", "Message"] !! fromEnum m) ++ ' ' : show (messageString m)
Main> case runParser parser () "" "ta" of Left pe -> errorMessages pe
[SysUnExpect "\"t\"",SysUnExpect "",SysUnExpect "",Expect "\"head\"",Expect "\"tail\"",Expect "\"tales\""]
```

You can see that **secretly** `choice` is dumping all of its information into a bunch of parallel messages, and storing "unexpected end-of-file" as `SysUnExpect ""`. The `show` instance for `ParseError` apparently grabs the first `SysUnExpect` but all of the `Expect` messages and dumps them for you to see.

The exact function which does this at present is [Text.Parsec.Error:showErrorMessages](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.9/docs/src/Text-Parsec-Error.html#showErrorMessages). The error messages are expected to be in order and are broken into 4 chunks based on the constructor; the `SysUnExpect` chunk is sent through a special display function which hides the text completely if there are bona-fide `UnExpect` elements or else shows only the first `SysUnExpect` message:

```
  showSysUnExpect | not (null unExpect) ||
                    null sysUnExpect = ""
                  | null firstMsg    = msgUnExpected ++ " " ++ msgEndOfInput
                  | otherwise        = msgUnExpected ++ " " ++ firstMsg
```

It may be worth rewriting this or sending a bug upstream, as this is kinda weird behavior, and the data structures don't quite suit them. First, your problem in a nutshell is: it seems like each `Message` should have a `SourcePos`, not each ParseError.

So, there is an earlier step, `mergeErrors`, which prefers ParseErrors with later `SourcePos`-es. This doesn't fire because messages don't have a `SourcePos`, which means that all of the errors from `choice` start at the beginning of the string rather than at the maximal point matched. You can see this for example in how this doesn't get stuck on parsing `"tai"`:

```
let parser = try (string "head") <|> choice (map (try . (string "ta" >>) . string) ["il", "les"]) :: GenParser Char st Strinh
```

Second, apart from that, probably we should bind together messages that go together (so the default message is `unexpected 't', expected "heads" | unexpected end-of-file, expected 'tails' | unexpected end-of-file, expected 'tales'` unless you override it with `<?>`). Third, probably the ParseError constructor should be exported; fourth, the enumerated type in `Message` is really ugly and might be better put into `ParseError {systemUnexpected :: [Message], userUnexpected :: [Message], expected :: [Message], other :: [Message]}` or something, even in its present incarnation. (For example, the current `Show` for `ParseError` will break subtly if the messages aren't in a certain order.)

In the meantime I would recommend writing your own `show` variant for `ParseError`.

Comment: Same version. And you are correct: this works. My example was bad. I edited the question, it's using different strings now. I don't know why the first example did work, maybe because all the strings were of the same length.

Comment: @snøreven added another section that may help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed analysis of the problem. I filed a bug and referenced your answer here.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I've got with Parsec:

```
λ> let parser = choice $ fmap (try . string) ["head", "tail", "tales"]
λ> parseTest parser "ta"
parse error at (line 1, column 1):
unexpected "t"
expecting "head", "tail" or "tales"
```

If you care to try modern version of Parsec —
[Megaparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec), you will end
up with:

```
λ> let parser = choice $ fmap (try . string) ["head", "tail", "tales"]
λ> parseTest parser "ta"
1:1:
unexpected "ta" or 't'
expecting "head", "tail", or "tales"
```

What's going on here? First, when we parse ordered collection of characters,
like with `string`, we display incorrect input completely. This is much
better in our opinion because:

```
λ> parseTest (string "when" <* eof) "well"
1:1:
unexpected "we"
expecting "when"
```

We're pointing to beginning of the word and we show the whole thing that is
not correct (up to first mismatching character) and the whole thing we
expect. This is more readable in my opinion. Only parsers built on `tokens`
work this way (that is, when we're trying to match fixed string,
case-insensitive variant is available).

Then, what about `unexpected "ta" or 't'`, why do we get `'t'` part? This is
also absolutely correct, because with your collection of alternatives, the
first letter `'t'` can be also unexpected by itself because you have
an alternative that doesn't start with `'t'`. Let's see another example:

```
λ> let parser = choice $ fmap (try . string) ["tall", "tail", "tales"]
λ> parseTest parser "ta"
1:1:
unexpected "ta"
expecting "tail", "tales", or "tall"
```

Or how about:

```
λ> parseTest (try (string "lexer") <|> string "lexical") "lex"
1:1:
unexpected "lex"
expecting "lexer" or "lexical"
```

Parsec:

```
λ> parseTest (try (string "lexer") <|> string "lexical") "lex"
parse error at (line 1, column 1):
unexpected end of input
expecting "lexical"
```

Why take pains to make it work when it can “just work”?

There are many other great things about Megaparsec, if you're interested,
you can learn more about it
[here](https://github.com/mrkkrp/megaparsec). It's hard to compete with
Parsec, but we have written our own tutorials and our docs are very good.

Comment: Interesting, wasn't aware there is another parser library. Problem: your documentation links to non-existing tutorials (link on page links to itself). I'm new to Haskell and would have liked to see some example usage (with type signatures and everything).

Comment: @snøreven, there is menu at the bottom. Sorry, I will have to move it, since it's not very obvious. Here is the direct link: https://mrkkrp.github.io/megaparsec/tutorials.html.